# Form to Store $request and back to view in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a form that posts to a the store function in my Controller called Summary.

Store Function ( standard with laravel 5.2)

```
public function store(Request $request)
```

If i use

```
return $request->all()
```

I can see the data that i posted from my form (it displays it on a blank page).

I can create variables from the data

```
$name = $request->name;
```

How do i display this data now on the same view where the form is. I have text boxes with name , surname and email. once clicked it performs the above. I would like to display the post data below the form. Usually i would use ISSET on the page and then echo out the data.

I have tried :

```
$data = $request->all();
return view('search', compact('data'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are wanting to do is share functions within your class.
take a look at this documentation. [Laravel Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers)